# Get exit code for eval command in sh

Tags: eval, sh, exit, xcodebuild

I'm trying to create a function in a shell script that takes a command and executes it using eval, and then does some post-processing based on the success of the command. Unfortunately the code is not behaving as I would expect. Here's what I have:

```
#!/bin/sh

...

function run_cmd()
{
        # $1 = build cmd

        typeset cmd="$1"
        typeset ret_code

        eval $cmd
        ret_code=$?

        if [ $ret_code == 0 ]
        then
                # Process Success
        else
                # Process Failure
        fi

}

run_cmd "xcodebuild -target \"blah\" -configuration Debug"
```

When the command (`$cmd`) succeeds, it works fine. When the command fails ( compilation error, for instance ), the script automatically exits before I can process the failure. Is there a way I can prevent eval from exiting, or is there a different approach I can take that will allow me achieve my desired behavior?

Comment: there should be no automatic exit unless you have `set -e` somewhere in your script. If you have it, `set +e` will disable it.

Comment: *sigh* I had `set -o errexit` lingering at the top of the caller script. Thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The script should only exit if you have `set -e` somewhere in the script, so I'll assume that is the case.  A simpler way to write the function which will prevent `set -e` from triggering an automatic exit is to do:

```
run_cmd() {
        if eval "$@"; then
                # Process Success
        else
                # Process Failure
        fi
}
```

Note that `function` is non-portable when defining the function, and redundant if `()` are also used.